# Finding zipcodes within line using GeoPandas

Tags: python, polygon, line, geopandas, zip-codes

I have a shapefile of Houston zip codes and gdb folder of lines (within Houston). 
The lines are in a gdb folder containing over 125 files. The types of files included in this folder are `GDBINDEXES`, `GDBTABLE`, `GDBTABLX`, `ATX`, `SPX`, and etc. When I add this whole folder as a layer on ArcMap I get a series of different lines and ArcMap labels the layer as edges. Each line starts at one coordinate and ends at another coordinate.

I want to figure out which zip codes each line crosses using GeoPandas. I have over 500,000 lines. I have no previous experience using GeoPandas.

Comment: GDBINDEXES, GDBTABLE, GDBTABLX, etc. are not featureclasses. They are just database files. If you open GDB folder in ArcCatalog(or in Catalog panel in ArcMap), you will see featureclasses in GDB. Windows treats GDB like a folder. But ArcGIS treats like a database.

Comment: Try to add layers using Catalog panel or ArcCatalog(Drag and drop). How many layers do you see after doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by "Each line starts at one coordinate and ends at another coordinate". Every line (except polyline) starts at a point and ends at a point. Do yo mean "Each line has one segment which contains only two points, start and end"?

Answer (score 4):

Sample shapefiles:

[image]

Use this script. Change paths.

```
import geopandas as gpd

# Read shapefiles. Change paths
zipcodes = gpd.read_file(r"C:\PATH\TO\ZIPCODE.shp")
lines = gpd.read_file(r"C:\PATH\TO\LINES.shp")

df = gpd.sjoin(lines, zipcodes, op="intersects")    
# ZIPCODE: zip codes column name in your shapefile. Don't forget to change it
lines["zip_codes_intersected"] = df.groupby(df.index).agg({'ZIPCODE': list})
print(lines)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    geometry                        zip_codes_intersected
0   LINESTRING (3089072.017 ....    [77055, 77080, 77092]
1   LINESTRING (3070881.072 ....    [77092, 77091, 77040]
2   LINESTRING (3116245.361 ....    [77009, 77008]
```

Comment: I just noticed that the lines are in a gdb folder (not a shapefile, sorry about that) containing over 125 files ( the types of files included in this folder are GDBINDEXES , GDBTABLE, GDBTABLX , ATX, SPX, and etc.) When i add this whole folder as a layer on arcmap i get a series of different lines and arcmap labesls the layer as edges. How would I approach the problem when this is the case?